# eclipse: c/c++ build / builder settings page is disabled (grey), can't change settings

Tags: eclipse

I have an empty C++ project in Eclipse, and I want to use a custom makefile. When I go to project properties and click "C/C++ Build", the "Builder Settings" tab is disabled, and I cannot customize the build command.

How can I apply my own makefile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can only customize the builder settings if you choose an empty **makefile** project.

delete the project, keeping the contents on the disk.  then click file -> new -> c++ project.  instead of choosing "empty project" under "executable", choose "empty project" under "makefile project".

Comment: This works but sadly still in 2019, non-CDT-managed projects like the Makefile project are practically impossible to setup for correct code indexing

Answer (score 9):

The problem is actual on windows and appears when you using toolchains. [I found small hack to correct it](http://rtorsten.blogspot.com/2012/05/eclipse-cdt-disabled-build-settings.html).

Comment: Sadly chaning toolchain to anything other than CDT internal builder removes multiple tabs from C/C++ build -> settings which makes it practically imposible to setup working indexer. You can either customize build command OR have a working indexer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to MSVC projects, note that CDT support is **still in beta** (so essentially, abandoned)